# In what situation do we use ATTR Function in Tableau?

Tags: function, tableau-api, attr

As the title, why and in what situation do we use ATTR Function in Tableau?
i understand what it is, and its simplest form.
thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

I know you say you understand what it is in its simplest form, but just for folks who stumble upon this question, I'd also offer [this blog post](https://interworks.com/blog/tcostello/2014/05/15/attr-tableaus-attribute-function-explained/), which gives an example and a "plain English" break-down of [this Tableau Knowledge Base article](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/when-to-use-the-attribute-attr-function) "When to Use the Attribute (ATTR) Function". This same article is also linked to in [this older SO question of a similar vein](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416290/can-someone-please-explain-the-attr-function-in-tableau).

In a phrase from the blog post:

> It returns a value if it is unique, else it returns *

As another example, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753054/tableau-calculating-average-where-date-is-less-than-value-from-another-data-so) discusses ATTR in the context of calculating an average where date is less than the value from another data source.

Answer (score 0):

The typical case is for a tooltip where most of the time there is only one value for a field among all the data rows at the level of detail of the viz, but there are a few exceptions. In that case, you may not want to create new marks by treating the field as a dimension, which would increase the level of detail of the viz. This is so common that Tableau automatically uses ATTR() when you put dimensions on the tooltip shelf.

Other cases are when you are putting a dimension on the detail or row shelves, and want to "debug" the level of detail of your viz. Say, you expect that using A, B, and C as dimensions will cause each mark to have the same value for D. You can use ATTR(D) to concisely show which combinations of A, B, C  differ from your expectation.

ATTR is also useful with calculated fields in some cases, say in a IF condition when defining an aggregate calc.